# Sharing an External Hard Drive between Users

Tags: 14.04, external-hdd

On Ubuntu 14.04, I would like to be able to share an external USB hard drive between users. I have two users, my girlfriend and I, and an HDD that usually remains connected. It's not always connected, so I don't want to add it to fstab.

The drive mounts for whoever is logged in first when the system starts up, or whoever is active when it is connected. When I switch users, the second user cannot access the drive.

I installed Users and Groups from gnome-system-tools (Why this was removed, I'll never understand) and set both users to each others groups. The Andrew group has both Andrew and Hannah as users, and the Hannah group has both Andrew and Hannah as users. If I look at the directory permissions, it shows Me/Create and delete files, andrew (group)/none, others/none. I cannot change the group access. It just reverts back to none immediately.

I tried to `sudo chmod -R 777 /media` and it still doesn't modify access to the drive.

I've run out of ideas and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, the drive is NTFS.

Comment: Okay. That's a good point and one I had certainly forgotten. Are there any options here then? If I unplug the device, change users, reconnected the device, it remounts as the new user but that's certainly a hassle for something connected behind the computer. Are the NTFS permissions being set when the device is mounted and cannot be modified until remounted?

Comment: I tried to be as generic as possible.

Answer (score 3):

If the disk is formatted as EXT4 you can use the "groups" to set the disk to a group both users belong too. Permissions on a Linux system are normally set to 755 for folders and 644 for files. But you can change that to 775 and 664, and set a group and then add both users to the group. Both will then be able to execute the disk, store and remove files. Basically all you would want.

If the disk is formatted as NTFS you need to provide user and group during the mounting of the disk. You have the dmask (directory), fmask (file) and umask (user) options for that. To set the owner, use the uid and gid. Similar to EXT you set the GID and add both users to the GID.

"chmod" and "chown" do not work when the disk is mounted. It is a foreign file system that does not support these.

By the way: it is best to add it to `/etc/fstab`. That the disk is not always present should not be a problem.

Generic example:

```
{uuid}  /mnt/{directory}  ntfs-3g   noauto gid=users,umask=0002    0       0
```

where "users" is your group and "umask" is the reverse of chmod (0002= 775 allowing for execute by group). A lot of information can be found om the [NTFS-3G page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G#Allowing_group.2Fuser) made by the cool dudes using Arch. There is also the official [NTFS-3G manual](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/). The "noauto" prevents auto mounting.

If you want to [manual mount](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G#Manual_mounting):

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/your_NTFS_partition /mount/point
```

or

```
ntfs-3g /dev/your_NTFS_partition /mount/point
```

It will then pick up the options set in /etc/fstab

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I was under the impression that if a device in the fstab was not present at boot, that it would hang. If that's not the case, then that should certainly be a viable option.

Comment: That's is where 'noauto' comes in ;-)

Comment: Could auto be used with nofail to mount if it's present and still boot if it isn't?

Comment: If there is any flaw in there or you have questions PM me and I shall respond :=)

Comment: @AndrewCrow the "nobootwait" is probably a better option

Comment: For ext4 filesystems, how do you "change that to 775 and 664, and set a group and then add both users to the group"? How do you write a chmod / chown command selectively for files and folders? Would appreciate a sample command with group syntax! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the menu, go to System > Users and Groups, and there, select the user, click on "advanced settings" button, and in the "User Privileges" tab, mark the option "Access External Storage Devices Automatically". It should do the job.